# How to stretch a image in grid view CSS

Tags: css, sass

How can I stretch the images into grid cell. More specifically I want to remove left and right padding showing in the snap photo.
CSS code:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.container img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: fill;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
.container img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.04);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

[Grid images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsN8L.png)

Comment: Please add some html code. If possible, a working code snippet would be helpful to answer. Have you tried changing the `width` and `height` of the image too `100%`?

Comment: Yes I tried width height 100%, but didn't worked.